# Meaning of "throw some work your way"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I think probably the expression means to find job for someone, Is it a common expression or a word made inside the movie?

> *I talked to him. He said he can "throw some work my way".*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it means give someone some work to do. it implies two things: firstly that the work is not permanent employment, but some short term work; secondly, that the work is for pay.

it is an extremely common expression.

Comment: I would recognise it also with some other words instead of "throw", such as "send", "push", "toss".

Comment: Would the phrase also work with different things in place of "work"? Could someone throw e.g. a problem/challenge/project somebody's way?

Answer (score 2):

It means to give somebody some work to do, for example to keep somebody busy (and thus billable).